# can not get to all the element of ng-repeat in Protractor test by each(), which use to work in 1.4.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor

**This Code use to work in Protractor 1.4.0::**

```
 element.all(by.repeater('item in vm.occupations'))
    .each(function(jobsInRepeater) {
        jobsInRepeater.element(by.binding('item.Title'))
            .click()
            .then(function(){//someLogic});
```

***protractor 2.1.0 gives the follwing error for this code***

```
 Message:
 ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible(Session info:chrome=43.0.2357.124)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)   Stacktrace:
 ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.124)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: wrong selector? `item in vm.occupations` - note missing space after `in`

Comment: its works fine if i run on protractor version 1.4.0, but when i change protractor version to latest it fails..

Comment: Have you tried to run `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: ya its updated to the latest version